# Radius of convergence of $f(z)=\frac{z^4e^z}{(6-z)(2i-z)} $

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

The Question is:

> Compute the radius of convergence for the expansion at the point
> $z=4+3i$ of the function $$f(z)=\frac{z^4e^z}{(6-z)(2i-z)}. $$

In my text book the solution is written like this:
$\sqrt{(4-6)^2+3^2}$,  but I don't understand how they calculate it. Can someone please explain it?

Thanks!

Comment: The Radius of Convergence is the shortest distance from $4+3i$ to one of the poles.

Comment: It is the minimum of the distances from $4+3i$ to the poles $6$ and $2i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{6, 2i\}$. The Radius of Convergence is given by the minimum of the distances from $4+3i$ to $z = 6$ or $z = 2i$. That's due to the fact that we can write $f$ as a power series on $D_R(4+3i)$ (meaning the open disc of radius $R$ around $4+3i$). You also might fancy a look at [Radius of Convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence).

The distance from $4 + 3i$ to $z = 2i$ is given by $\sqrt{4^2 + 1^2}$. The distance from $4 +3i$ to $z = 6$ is given by $\sqrt{2^2 + 3^2}$. This will immediately become clear if you draw a figure and use Pythagoras.

Since
\begin{align}
\sqrt{17} = \sqrt{4^2 + 1^2} > \sqrt{2^2 + 3^2} = \sqrt{13}
\end{align}
and $R = \operatorname{min}\{\sqrt{4^2 + 1^2}, \sqrt{2^2 + 3^2}\}$ we find $R = \sqrt{2^2 + 3^2}$ or as the text book has written it: $R = \sqrt{(4-6)^2 + 3^2}$.